# Automatically manage whitelisting (e.g. in tinyproxy) of dynamic IPs?

Tags: security, iptables, ip

I have a VPS that runs tinyproxy for private use, and another that runs nginx for development. Is there a protocol/daemon that I can use to automate whitelisting for my *dynamic* IP? So that tinyproxy only accepts connections from, and nginx only serves to, my IP.

Right now I use a sub-domain, like `123.123.0.0/16`, but that still seems vulnerable, and sometimes my ISP, just to mess with me, changes the second quad.

I'm thinking I can do it via a bash script, iptables and noip, but these are my concerns:

- Dependence on third-party services.
- I'll need multiple dynamic IP names (and therefore possibly a paid account) for multiple devices (home, work, mobile, tablet).
- Additional point of failure; if noip goes down, I'll be stuck without access.

I had the idea today to write a daemon to automate this, I think it could be a fun exercise, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Here's how I was thinking it should work. If there isn't one single solution, maybe part of this is done already:

- A bracketed section in config files that is reserved by the program. For example, in *tinyproxy.conf*:

`#!-autowhitelist section-do not change anything below this--`

`allow 123.123.123.123
 allow 123.123.123.124`

`#-!-autowhitelist section-do not change anything above this--`

- Server runs on a port, accepting all connections. .
- Client connects to that port, requests registration.
- Server performs authentication (via pre-stored public-key challenge-response)
- If authenticated, scans through tinyproxy.conf and replaces the allow lines with the last *n* (configurable) unique clients to register.
- Runs `service tinyproxy reload` (which should honor existing connections I'd think).
- Alternately it could modify rules for `iptables`, I have yet to consider which would be the better solution. System-level whitelisting is probably more secure and robust, but config-level is more flexible and allows for logging, etc.

The server program could have dynamic scripts that could handle different formats of config files (one for tinyproxy, one for nginx, maybe even one for sshd if I'm feeling adventurous, etc.).

Any thoughts, security holes you can see in this?

Comment: I would create an IPsec tunnel between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hadn't thought about it. Do you mean instead of public-key C/R, or instead of the whole auto-whitelisting approach in the first place?

Comment: You can keep TLS on the site, extra layers of security  do not hurt. Instead of the auto-whitelisting.